# why accuracy is equal to f1 measure on binary classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, data-science

I am working on classification by combining PCA and LBP with SVM, KNN, Decision tree, random forest and AdaBoost. the output of accuracy and f1-score are all equal. I can't interpret the results. The number of positive and negative samples are equal in the test set.

Comment: That should only happen when precision are recall are equal, and it would be surprising for those to always be equal in your experiments, unless you have something that artificially forces the classifier to output the same number of +'s and -'s (since you said your test set has the same number too). I expect something is wrong in one of your calculations.